# any word ending with s but not ss is about genitiv？

Tags: word-usage

Is this a rule? I am new to German, I am using this to identify genitiv words.

Of course, the word 'das' is an exception.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a rule. Here are some examples:

- words with the suffix *-nis*
- *Ananas*
- *Anus*
- *Ausweis*
- *Bus*
- *Fels*
- *Gas*
- *Glas*
- *Gleis*
- *Gras*
- *Greis*
- *Haus*
- *Hinweis*
- *Kurs*
- *Lachs*
- *Mais*
- *Mus*
- *Pommes*
- *Praxis*
- *Preis*
- *Reis*
- *Tennis*
- *Usus*
- *Vlies*

Comment: [der Bus / des Busses](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Bus)

Comment: Since "das" is mentioned as an exception in the question: Of course there's also plenty of non-substantives that end in "s" but either don't have any case at all (e.g. adverbs like "morgens") or aren't genitive (adjectives like "mies", particularly neutral forms like "rotes").

Comment: @DonHolgo: Yes, this includes only nouns in the singular nominative. The *-s* ending is also sometimes used as a plural marker for nouns, so adding those would expand the list as well. I left out compounds as well; they don't really count anyway since they inherit their endings from the parent word. The list is not meant to be comprehensive, so I sure there are many more words that could be added, even if you only count nominative singular nouns,